# Is the Antminer S5 still worth it for low profit?

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-profitability, antminer

I'm thinking about getting an Antminer S5 for Christmas to jump start my Bitcoin mining adventure. Using CryptoCompare's profit calculator I see that I will be losing 60 cents per day with the current kWH in my area. I have yet to talk to my parents (I'm 14) about allowing me to get it and put it in the shed. If they let me and the electric bill increase won't bother them, would the Antminer S5 be worth it? If I were to pay my parents part of the cost, say $10-$15 since the estimated cost would be $20, would it still be a little profitable?

Comment: This means that your parents have to cover about 1200$ in electril bill for you per year.
It would be more profitable if you just ask them for 1200$ in allowance per year.

You will profit from both options, but on the expense of your parents.
Also, the S5 is quite loud and produce some heat, I would't sleep in the same room without ear plugs.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make much sense, you are asking if it is profitable yet you acknowledge that you will be losing 60 cent per day due to electricity costs.

Bitcoin mining is not very profitable unless you have zero or low electricity costs, and the constant increase in difficulty makes your hardware obsolete. It is more worthwhile to invest in a concurrency simply, and wait for the value to rise (if it does)

Is the Ant miner worth it?
Well, if you are going to lose 60 cents per day, it most likely is not, and as difficulty increases you will make less and less while losing more.

Anyways, it seems more like you want daily income at the expense of your parents (weather they realize the more expensive electric bill or not). It probably is not worth it.